What is the source of the quote: "the church is a hospital"?
There is an often-quoted saying of Augustine that “The church is not a hotel for saints, it is a hospital for sinners.”
However, in conducting a cursory search of the words on the internet, one finds a serious divergence in...

who might have said those words (Augustine of Hippo vs. Chrysostom)
what the quote actually was

My question is this then: Is there a way to find out...

who actually said those words?
where they are written (ideally, in the original Latin)?


Looks like it was Jean Phillips ("Dear Abby") paraphrasing the Gospel of Mark or something along those lines. https://ask.metafilter.com/240119/Reliably-sourcing-a-quote-about-the-church Please edit the question if you have any serious reason to think this quote could be attributed to Augustine or the others.

By the way, of course the Gospel of Mark was originally written in the Greek of the time, and (in any case) Augustine wrote in Latin (of the time). So far as I know, (the English words...) "hotel" and "hospital" were more-or-less the same, especially in Old/Middle French, and, for that matter, had almost no sense/content at all until the last 200 years. So I think it might be hard to really make a distinction in the desired sense...

FWIW, the Mark (2:17) passage in question is "On hearing this, Jesus said to them, “It is not the healthy who need a doctor, but the sick. I have not come to call the righteous, but sinners.”" - The quote asked about is clearly a modern rephrasing of the sentiment in the Mark passage, enough so that I'd suggest just referencing Mark's wording instead. If you're talking about the Church, Jesus (through Mark) is clearly a better authority than even St. Augustine or Dear Abby.

Jerome translated the Mark quote to latin in the Vulgate as: "illis non necesse habent sani medicum sed qui male habent", or in the Mat. 9:12 version "non est opus valentibus medico sed male habentibus".
